# Prevent duplicates on calendar events from google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, calendar

I dont know much of writting code in App script but i am trying to learn...
I need to write a code to fill calendar events from a google sheet but i dont know how to prevent the events from duplicate
My calendar event is simple with just a name of the event and date...no need for hours or location..etc..

here is my code so far...it is runing OK but makes duplicates everytime that i run the script

```
function CreateMultipleEvents() 
{
  const     calendar=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("36712b8ce88c7ea6db1c20d43131db4d9a106513b86d9f1d0668c8aa49f50752@group.calendar.google.com");
  const ws=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss=ws.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=2;i<=ss.getLastRow();i++)

{
  const eventName=ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
  const date=ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
  var startingDate=new Date(date)
  var endingDate=new Date(date)
  CalendarApp.createEvent(eventName,startingDate,endingDate);
  }
  for(var i=4;i<=ss.getLastRow();i++)
{
  const eventName2=ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
  const date=ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
  var startingDate=new Date(date)
  var endingDate=new Date(date)
  CalendarApp.createEvent(eventName2,startingDate,endingDate);
}
```

}

Can you please help?

Thanks a lot!

I just need to be able to write a script that prevents duplicates of the events

Comment: There was a script similar to this the other day. As each new event was created , the script got the Event ID and saved that to the spreadsheet. The result was that when looping through the spreadsheet, if the event details already have an event id, then the script can skip that row since the event has already been created. Also works for changes in event details since you already know the Event ID.